# how to create dynamic controls and events?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i created a dynamic control but i want to create events dynamically for the control for example button i created a dynamic  button like.

```
    Button btn = new Button();       
    btn.Text = "click";       
    form1.Controls.Add(btn);
```

Comment: will you be creating more than one button? if so, should the event handler be the same for each one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the Init event of the page, by simply setting the btn.Clicked event to the appropriate delegate.

```
btn.Clicked += this.btnClickedEventHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

but = new Button();
but.Click += new EventHandler(this.button_Click);
form1.Controls.Add(but);